# Curl or Mysql server usage

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Im trying to make a decision but im struggling. I have a couple of choices.

1 option is to have each user run a mysql query every 10seconds, the other is for them to use curl to pull the results from another page.

The Query is pulling 80values from a db (2columns, 40 rows).

Im just not sure which is worst for resources.

Comment: for 2 columns and 40 rows? how much users are we talking about? more than  1000 at a time?

Comment: It would vary between 1-40 at peak times (40 being very rare) avg about 10

Comment: then it doesn't matter if they pull data directly from database.

Comment: are all users seeing the same values? or user specific content?

Comment: Its always the same just updated incase anything has been added in the previous 10sec

Comment: This wouldn't affect performance whichever configuration. You could e reading that same data from 80 different local files and no big impact would be felt. Scaling that upwards would cause an impact

Comment: MySQL knows how to deliver same content with temporary tables.

Comment: In my opinion database would be better option than curl in anycase

Comment: @MihaiIorga Temp tables are not needed; the query cache will eat these things like peanuts.

Comment: How much data is in the table. Is that the 80 values or are there millions or rows and they only need 80 values?

Comment: @MihaiStancu :) internal temp tables ..

Comment: @Fluty indeed curl will be less fast but imagin 10*80*1KB => 0.8MB of data... benchmarking such a difference is a challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have switched over to using Memcache and using Ajax as reloader, this has massively reduced server load.

Thanks for all feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. You have a straightforward choice between two different dataflow alternatives.

You've said you have 1-40 users, but mostly at the low end of that user count. You haven't said whether this is a web app or a direct-connect app, but you're using php so it's probably a web app.

You've said you need to reload and, presumably, re-display, a result set of 40 short rows to each user.

You've said you need to do this every ten seconds.

You *haven't* described the origin of your ten second specification. Presumably something changes in the result set often enough to justify the ten second refresh.

You *haven't* described whether each of your users gets a different result set, or whether they are all the same.  But it doesn't really make much difference.

So, what are the choices and issues? Let's work through it.

A. Use a MySQL query for each refresh.

B. Fetch another web page (using curl) for each refresh.

1. Pro A. Your system will be simpler and less prone to fail because of system trouble.
2. Pro A. It's much easier to program and test.
3. Pro A. Failures in production will be easier to diagnose and repair.
4. Con A. Hitting the MySQL data base with 40 x 40 x 6 requests a minute seems like a lot.
5. Con 4. But you still have to generate the web page you're going to grab with CURL.
6. Con 4. If your system gets a heavy load, you can degrade gracefully by changing 10 seconds to 30 or some such.
7. Con 4. MySQL is pretty fast in its handling of small cached requests.
8. Pro B. If that web page you're sucking up with CURL is already generated, this may be faster.
9. Con 8. But it's still a more complex operation.
10. Pro A. Adding RAM to a server is MUCH cheaper than adding labor to a complex system.

Based on this analysis (which is based on my imperfect understanding of your system) MySQL is definitely the way to go. You may be able to enlarge this analysis with your understanding.